# Are There Any Rails Modules or Classes Which Provide Frozen HTML Content Type Strings?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, memory

Ive been searching through [source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/c082a7aae4a41b52e58c7dea43e7e9c6c41d11ad/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_types.rb) for a while, and it appears to me that there are no given Rails tools for retrieving the String representation of various HTML content types. Ive also found this to be a very difficult concept to search for in general.

What I want is something like this:

`Mime::Mimes::CONTENT_TYPE_JSON = 'application/json'.freeze`

or, `Mime::Mimes::CONTENT_TYPES[:json]` etc.

...because I want to do a lot of things like `some_value == 'application/json'` or `some_value = 'application/json'` etc.

I want to use the expression "application/json" often, and I dont want to create new String instances for something that is pretty well within the domain of web application development. Ive thought of creating my own app consts or vars so I dont have to allocate HTML Content Type strings more than once, but also feel this should just be available for me in any web application framework (at least, those written in languages where every string is a new memory allocation).

Is there a better tool or resource within the Rails 5 source that I am missing that allows easy retrieval of content type strings? Do I have to get a gem / create my own for this?

Note: Im away of how heavy of an "optimization" this may appear to be. Let's then entertain this query from a position of being pragmatic about organizational style, for a project that requires elimination of any duplication of domain-specific string literals, and to keep them symbolized or as some frozen const. Let's pretend its a personal project for the sheer joy of experimenting with such style!

Comment: In the scope of a web application, this string allocation  is a minuscule amount of memory / processing. Making a variable/constant reference to the string is maybe good from an organization perspective, but will probably have little effect for optimization.

Comment: Be careful, this is called premature optimization and it's really a bad thing to try to be careful to. I fell in that trap when I was younger. The truth is, by the time you need to be careful for string allocation, you either are rich or out of job already. Otherwise, if you need to be careful for string allocation **upfront**, it means _you are not using the right tool for the job_. If that's the case, probably you need C or C++, sure you don't want to use Ruby for that case.

Comment: Thanks, maxple, and @Fire-Dragon-DoL. I have about 10 years experience dealing with memory optomizations in production. I have learned the perils of preoptimization the hard way, many years in the past.  My questions still stand. Lets pretend its a personal project for the pure joy of pragmatic programming!

Comment: Thanks @maxple, I tend to agree. I get my thrills and lulz from organization.

Comment: Hey @Todd I think your best bet is use http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Mime/Type.html and you can loop over all the mime types in there and freeze them, or create your own constant and freeze them based on that constant (so you don't have to write it yourself)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a new module to facilitate simple storage and retrieval using the `ActionPack` `Mime::Type` system would work as follows:

```
# Build hash of type name to value, e.g., { xml: "application/xml" }
CONTENT_TYPES = {}.tap do |simple_content_types_hash|
  # Get each registered Mime Type
  Mime::EXTENSION_LOOKUP.each do |mime|
    simple_content_type_hash[mime.first.to_sym] = mime.last.instance_variable_get("@string").freeze
  end
end.freeze
```

Note: the above is untested, its just a generalization of what I am looking for. Thanks to @Fire-Dragon-DoL for the tip.

This could be added via an initializer, patched into an existing module, or into a new helper module.

Answer (score 2):

There is a shorthand for it:

```
Mime[:json]
```

`Mime#[]` -
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/e2efc667dea886e71c33e3837048e34b7a1fe470/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_type.rb#L41

which uses

`Mime::Type#lookup_by_extension` -
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/e2efc667dea886e71c33e3837048e34b7a1fe470/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_type.rb#L149

If you want to get the actual content type you might need to call a `#to_s` on it:

```rb
Mime[:json].to_s
```